# Como desenhar uma imagem com Canvas?

Tags: java, swing, awt

Eu tenho esse código e quero desenhar uma imagem:

```
public void render(){
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null)
    {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [método `drawImage(Image, int, int, ImageObserver)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage-java.awt.Image-int-int-java.awt.image.ImageObserver-) para desenhar uma imagem no seu `Graphics`:

```
public void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    File arquivoComImagem = new File(...);
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(arquivoComImagem );
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
```

No caso, o primeiro parâmetro do `drawImage` é a imagem a ser desenhada. Há várias formas de se você obter uma instância de `Image`, mas uma das mais fáceis é usar o [método `ImageIO.read(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read-java.io.File-). Os dois parâmetros `int` do método `drawImage` são a posição `x` e `y` no `Graphics` em que você quer desenhar a imagem. O último parâmetro (o `ImageObserver`) você provavelmente não vai precisar, e você pode sempre passar `null` lá.